# Fibonacci: non-recursive vs memoized recursive puzzling timing results

Tags: algorithm, performance, go, recursion

After watching an MIT lecture on dynamic programming, I felt like practicing a bit with Fibonacci. I first wrote the naive recursive implementation and then added memoization. Here is the memoized version:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func fib_memoized(n int, memo map[int]int64) int64 {
    memoized, ok := memo[n]
    if ok {
        return memoized
    }
    if n < 2 {
        return int64(n)
    }
    f := fib_memoized(n-2, memo) + fib_memoized(n-1, memo)
    memo[n] = f
    return f
}

func main() {
    memo := make(map[int]int64)
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("fib(%d) = %d\n", i, fib_memoized(i, memo))
    }
}
```

I then proceeded to write a non-recursive version of the program:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func fib(n int) int64 {
    var f1 int64 = 1
    var f2 int64 = 0
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        f1, f2 = f2, f1+f2
    }
    return f2
}

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("fib(%d) = %d\n", i, fib(i))
    }
}
```

What has puzzled me is the fact that the memoized version seems to perform at least as well as the non-recursive one and, sometimes, even outperform it. Naturally, I was expecting memoization to bring great improvements in comparison to the naive recursive implementation, but I just haven't been able to figure out why/how the memoized version could be on par and even surpass its non-recursive counterpart.

I did try looking into the assembly output (obtained with `go tool compile -S`) of both versions, but to no avail. I still see the `CALL` instructions in the memoized version and, to my mind, that should incur enough overhead to justify it being at least slightly outperformed by the non-recursive version.

Could anyone more knowledgeable help me understand what's going on?

P.S. I'm aware of integer overflow; I used 10000 just to increase the load.

Thank you.

Comment: You seem to be referring to a memoized recursive, a naive recursive and a non-recursive implementation, but you have only shown two. Which ones are you running and which do expect to be fastest? Can you re-write the question using Go benchmarking?

I would expect the non-recursive implementation to be faster than even a memoized recursive implementation because a) Go does not have good Tail Call Optimization, and b) your memoized implementation is not a tail call.

Comment: The reason I didn't include the naive version is because I didn't think it would benefit the discussion, since my question is really on the performance of the memoized recursive vs the non-recursive (or iterative) versions. Sorry about not using Go benchmarking. Anyway, it seems you've already added a response doing just that, which I will study. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One quite important thing to keep in mind: `memo` is preserved between iterations of the testbench. So the memoized version has at most two recursive calls per iteration of the loop in `main`. I.e. you allow the memoized version to keep memory between individual iterations, while the iterative version needs to calculate from scratch in each iteration.

Next point:
Writing benchmarks is tricky. Tiny details can have a significant impact on the outcome. E.g. the calls to `printf` most likely take a considerable time to execute, but don't actually account for the runtime of the fibonacci-calculation. I don't have any environment available to test how much the timing is actually affected by these IO-operations, but it's quite likely considerable. Especially since your algorithm is running for a rather minuscule 10000 iterations, or barely 100 microseconds, as can be seen in [@Brackens answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68023945/4668606).

So to summarize:
Drop the IO from the benchmark, start with an empty `memo` in each iteration and increase the number of iterations to get better timing.

Comment: That was it. My bad for not realizing I was making things easier for the memoized version with each iteration, as the map was being filled with pre-calculated results. Resetting the cache on each iteration caused the memoized version to be more than 10 times slower than the iterative one. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are asking why the memoized recursive implementation is not much faster than the iterative implementation. Though you mention a "naive recursive implementation" that you do not show?

Using benchmarking you can see the performance of both is comparable, maybe iterative is a little faster:

```golang
package kata

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "testing"
)

func fib_memoized(n int, memo map[int]int64) int64 {
    memoized, ok := memo[n]
    if ok {
        return memoized
    }
    if n < 2 {
        return int64(n)
    }
    f := fib_memoized(n-2, memo) + fib_memoized(n-1, memo)
    memo[n] = f
    return f
}

func fib(n int) int64 {
    var f1 int64 = 1
    var f2 int64 = 0
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        f1, f2 = f2, f1+f2
    }
    return f2
}

func BenchmarkFib(b *testing.B) {
    out, err := os.Create("/dev/null")
    if err != nil {
        b.Fatal("Can't open: ", err)
    }
    b.Run("Recursive Memoized", func(b *testing.B) {
        memo := make(map[int]int64)
        for j := 0; j < b.N; j++ {
            for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
                fmt.Fprintf(out, "fib(%d) = %d\n", i, fib_memoized(i, memo))
            }
        }
    })
    b.Run("Iterative", func(b *testing.B) {
        for j := 0; j < b.N; j++ {
            for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
                fmt.Fprintf(out, "fib(%d) = %d\n", i, fib(i))
            }
        }
    })
}
```

```
% go test -bench=.
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
pkg: github.com/brackendawson/kata
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8850H CPU @ 2.60GHz
BenchmarkLoop/Recursive_Memoized-12                13424             91082 ns/op
BenchmarkLoop/Iterative-12                         13917             82837 ns/op
PASS
ok      github.com/brackendawson/kata    4.323s
```

I expect your memoized recursive implementation is not much faster because:

1. Go does not have good Tail Call Optimization (TCO). As you may have seen from the assembly there are still CALLs, recursion is usually only faster if the CALLs can be optimised out.
2. Your memoized recursive implementation is not a tail call, the recursive call must be the last statement in the function to use TCOs.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your question, but there is a way to get the N-th Fibonacci number in log(N)
All you need is to raise the matrix
| 0 1 |
| 1 1 |
to the power N using [binary matrix exponentiation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/matrix-exponentiation/)

links to materials:
https://kukuruku.co/post/the-nth-fibonacci-number-in-olog-n/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eMXNWcbw75E

Comment: Thank you for sharing that. I didn't know of that technique.